# bootstrap add space between card rows

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to display a list of cards in a Bootstrap grid using this code :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row hidden-md-up">
        {% for shop in shops %}
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card">
                    {% if shop.image %}
                        <img src="{{shop.image.url}}" style="height:150px;" alt="Card image cap">
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p>
                            <b>{{shop.title}}</b><br>
                            <i class="material-icons">location_on</i> <b>{{shop.distance }} km away</b><br>
                            <a href="/like/{{shop.id}}"><i class="material-icons">thumb_up</i> Like</a><br>
                            <a href="/unlike/{{shop.id}}"><i class="material-icons">thumb_down</i> Unlike</a>
                         </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using col-md-3 to display 4 cards per row ( 12 / 3 = 4)

This is what I get :

[image]

As you can see, there is space between each card, however, there is no space between each row.

Comment: You can use default bootstrap 4 class ```mt-5``` to your row  like ```<div class="row hidden-md-up mt-5">```.. Here ```mt``` is ```margin-top``` and you can use the percentage as per you need ```mt-*``` here i have given it as ```5```..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try do add style to your row container and make it `margin-bottom="5px"`. 
Something like:

```
<div style="margin-bottom:5px">;
```

Comment: I added margin-bottom:40px to col-md-3 div and it worked. Thank you

Comment: No problem :) Im glad it works. That 5px was just an example :)